# Highcharts missing first date label on xAxis

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have some problem with Highcharts chart. I want to make chart with datetime axis every one day, but Highcharts cuts off first date label on the x axis, it should start from today's date not tomarrow. Tooltip shows date fine though. Are there some Highcharts settings, that I missing to make it work? I would appreciate your help. Thanks.

Code:

```
var s = {
        min: 0,
        max: 50,
        totalPoints: 12
    };

function getRandomData() {
    var data  = [],
        date  = new Date().getTime(),
        res   = [],
        numb;

    for (var i = 0; i < s.totalPoints; i += 1) {
        if (i > 0) date += 24 * 3600 * 1000;
        numb = Math.floor(Math.random() * (s.max - s.min + 1) + s.min);
        res.push([date, numb]);
    }


    return res;
}


$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
        },
        series: [{
            data: getRandomData()
        }]

    });
});
```

Live on: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29UMJ/)**

Comment: Set showFirstLabel and showLastLabel as true (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts)

Answer (score 4):

To show the first and last tick while having points that are in between your ticks for `datetime` you can use `xAxis.startOnTick` and `xAxis.endOnTick` set to `true`.

I've [updated your JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29UMJ/1/) as an example.

Comment: But, shouldn't then, the first series marker be vertically aligned with first date on the x-axis? like here: http://jsfiddle.net/sgm46/ ? still, it's not what I'm looking for

Comment: Are you saying my solution isn't what you are looking for? The reason it's not vertically aligned is that you are using datetime, and the time of your points are not 00:00. The point is somewhere between two dates, not exactly one of them. If you set the time to be 00:00 for each of your points you should be fine.

Comment: Look at the [Date object details](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) to see how you can for example `setHours` (and minutes, seconds...) on the date object you've created to get it vertically aligned. Also, a [updated JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/29UMJ/2/).